# alfresco 5.2 solr4 troubleshooting

Tags: alfresco, solr4

I have added `alfresco-spp-5.0.d.amp` (SharePoint Protocol) module to my `alfresco.war`, so that caused the following error to my solr4 :

```
 2018-04-25 12:44:00,018  ERROR [quartz.core.JobRunShell] [DefaultScheduler_Worker-6] Job DEFAULT.org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean#785aa4ce threw an unhandled Exception:
 org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobMethodInvocationFailedException: Invocation of method 'run' on target class [class org.alfresco.module.org_alfresco_module_wcmquickstart.jobs.DynamicCollectionProcessor] failed; nested exception is org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.LuceneQueryParserException: 03253095 Request failed 404 /solr4/alfresco/alfresco?wt=json&fl=DBID%2Cscore&rows=1000&df=TEXT&start=0&locale=en_US&alternativeDic=DEFAULT_DICTIONARY&fq=%7B%21afts%7DAUTHORITY_FILTER_FROM_JSON&fq=%7B%21afts%7DTENANT_FILTER_FROM_JSON
        at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean$MethodInvokingJob.executeInternal(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:321)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:114)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:563)
Caused by: org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.LuceneQueryParserException: 03253095 Request failed 404 /solr4/alfresco/alfresco?wt=json&fl=DBID%2Cscore&rows=1000&df=TEXT&start=0&locale=en_US&alternativeDic=DEFAULT_DICTIONARY&fq=%7B%21afts%7DAUTHORITY_FILTER_FROM_JSON&fq=%7B%21afts%7DTENANT_FILTER_FROM_JSON
        at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryHTTPClient.postQuery(SolrQueryHTTPClient.java:1159)
        at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryHTTPClient.postSolrQuery(SolrQueryHTTPClient.java:1109)
        at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryHTTPClient.executeQuery(SolrQueryHTTPClient.java:576)
        at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryLanguage.executeQuery(SolrQueryLanguage.java:58)
        at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrSearchService.query(SolrSearchService.java:355)
        at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrSearchService.query(SolrSearchService.java:159)
        at org.alfresco.repo.search.SearcherComponent.query(SearcherComponent.java:73)
        at org.alfresco.repo.search.AbstractSearcherComponent.query(AbstractSearcherComponent.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor614.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.SubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(SubsystemProxyFactory.java:79)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.query(Unknown Source)
        at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.SearchServiceSubSystemDelegator.query(SearchServiceSubSystemDelegator.java:98)
        at org.alfresco.module.org_alfresco_module_wcmquickstart.jobs.DynamicCollectionProcessor$1$1.execute(DynamicCollectionProcessor.java:253)
        at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:464)
        at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:333)
        at org.alfresco.module.org_alfresco_module_wcmquickstart.jobs.DynamicCollectionProcessor$1.doWork(DynamicCollectionProcessor.java:242)
        at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:555)
        at org.alfresco.module.org_alfresco_module_wcmquickstart.jobs.DynamicCollectionProcessor.runInternal(DynamicCollectionProcessor.java:237)
        at org.alfresco.module.org_alfresco_module_wcmquickstart.jobs.DynamicCollectionProcessor.run(DynamicCollectionProcessor.java:200)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor860.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:269)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean$MethodInvokingJob.executeInternal(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:312)
        ... 3 more
```

Comment: You juste have two lines of logs ?

Comment: It seems like there is no deployed solr.war in you tomcat server (`Request failed 404`)

Comment: solr.war is deployed and the  search box works fine !!

Answer (score 0):

According to the logs, your Alfresco scheduler is firing a Lucene query and it is causing this error. It throws LuceneQueryParserException because of improper Lucene query is being passed.